# Sum all possible combinations of 2 or more elements from vector

Tags: r

Suppose I have a vector `[50, 55, 57, 58, 60]`

I am trying to find a sum of all possible combinations of 3 elements

Example:

```
50+55+57 |
50+57+58 |
55+57+58
...
```

and so on

Comment: Try `combn(vec, 3, FUN = sum)`

Answer (score 3):

We use `combn` to get the combinations and either use the `FUN` argument to get the `sum`

```
combn(vec, 3, FUN = sum)
```

Or use the `colSums` on the `matrix` output

```
colSums(combn(vec, 3))
```

#### data

```
vec <- c(50, 55, 57, 58, 60)
```

Comment: Thanks, I should add that I also want to "see" associated combination of numbers, for example when I want to know which combination produces max sum

Answer (score 1):

Based on @akrun you can add this line to the solution, to get the associated combination which produces max sum.

```
combn(vec, 3)[, which.max(colSums(combn(vec ,3)))]
```